# reading JSON data remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

**UPDATE 1**

i try to implement and but when i hover over my topic and i see the TopicId and TopicName are null and i see the data in `myJSON` string.

what else i have to do? what i am missing?

```
Topic topic = new Topic();
 MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myJSON));
 //stream1.Position = 0;
 DataContractJsonSerializer serialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Topic));
 //topic = (Topic)serialize.ReadObject(stream1);
 Topic p2 = (Topic)serialize.ReadObject(stream1);
 stream1.Close();  //later i will use in `using statement`
 stream1.Dispose();
```

PS: i just have only `Topic` class is that enough or do i have to create all the classes that jcolebrand showed below?

i have created a class called Topic and in it i have two prop

```
[DataContract] 
    public class Topic 
    {       
        [DataMember]
        public string TopicId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TopicName { get; set; } 
    }
```

**UPDATE 1 END**

I am working on a requirement that returns  JSON data and I need a way to parse the data and load that data into a dropdownlist and I'm looking for the element in JSON called `TopicName`

after the TopicName is extracted I will load that data into a DropDownList asp.net control
(not using JQuery or JavaScript)

here is JSON data:

```
[{"NS":{"Count":1},
  "Source":{"Acronym":"ABC","Name":"Name"},
  "Item":[{"Id":"12312",
           "Url":"http://sitename",
           "ContentItem":[{"NS":{"Count":1},
                           "SourceUrl":"sitename",
                           "ContentType":"text/xml",
                           "PersistentUrl":"sitename",
                           "Title":"MY TITLE",
                           "SelectionSpec":{"ClassList":"","ElementList":"","XPath":null},
                           "Language":{"Value":"eng","Scheme":"ISO 639-2"},
                           "Source":{"Acronym":"ABC","Name":"Name","Id":null},
                           "Topics":[{"Scheme":"ABC",
                                      "Topic":[{"TopicId":"6544","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME1"},
                                               {"TopicId":"63453","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME2"},
                                               {"TopicId":"2343","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME3"},
                                               {"TopicId":"2342","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME4"}]
                                    }],
                           "ContentBody":null
                        }]
         }]
 },

[{"NS":{"Count":1},"Source":{"Acronym":"ABC1","Name":"Name1"},"Item":[{"Id":"123121","Url":"http://sitename1","ContentItem":[{"NS":{"Count":1},"SourceUrl":"sitename","ContentType":"text/xml","PersistentUrl":"sitename1","Title":"MY TITLE1","SelectionSpec":{"ClassList":"","ElementList":"","XPath":null},"Language":{"Value":"eng","Scheme":"ISO 639-2"},
"Source":{"Acronym":"ABC1","Name":"Name1","Id":null},"Topics":[{"Scheme":"ABC1","Topic":[{"TopicId":"65441","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME11"},{"TopicId":"634531","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME21"},{"TopicId":"23431","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME31"},{"TopicId":"23421","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME41"}]}],"ContentBody":null}]}]},
```

Comment: can you check my indentation on this object and make sure it's indented as the object structure indicates? Knowing that it's correctly indented will help ensure a proper answer.

Comment: @jcolebrand: thanks for indent my code, how did you do? using any tool? just curious

Comment: thanks so much for your effort 1+

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the re-indent as applied above is correct, then you have the following classes (apparently)

```
public class OuterWrapper {
  public NS NS { get; set; }
  public Source Source { get; set; }
  public ContentItemWrapper[] Item { get; set; } 
}
public class ContentItemWrapper {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Url { get; set; }
  public ContentItem[] ContentItem { get; set; }
}
public class ContentItem {
  public NS NS { get; set; }
  public SourceUrl { get; set; }
  // I'm gonna skip a bunch of fields, you get the idea
  public Topics Topic { get; set; }
}
public class Topics {
  public string Scheme { get; set; }
  public Topic[] Topic { get; set; }
}
public class Topic {
  public string TopicId { get; set; }
  public string TopicName { get; set; }
}
```

And what you do is you use that set of type declarations (specifically the OuterWrapper) to DataContractJsonSerializer decode the JSON into a C# object that you can then query using strongly typed methods, etc. This is one of those times where C# doesn't have anywhere near the flexibility of Javascript, because everything has to be explicitly declared.

Comment: i have updated my question, i try to implement but no avail any help?

Comment: if your JSON string is everything you showed above, the edit you made won't work. Try making your JSON string ___only___ the following and try again: `{"Topic":{"TopicId":"6544","TopicName":"TOPIC NAME1"} }` (I think that's right)

Comment: Better would be (so you can learn how it needs to read it in) `Topic topic = new Topic{ TopicId = "6544", TopicName = "TOPIC NAME1" };  MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Topic)); ser.WriteObject(stream1, topic); stream1.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
Console.Write("JSON form of Topic object: ");
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());`

Comment: I am sure it will work if i have just tipicid and tipicname in json but i have long string of data and somehow i just needs to grab just id,name

Comment: So ... you want the application to just magically know it? I've given you the basic structure of what you must do. Welcome to inter-service programming. You have to have a long list of classes whenever you do this sort of thing. Some of the generated files I've seen from actual apps have 20k lines of classes generated like this.

Comment: no i dont expect to happen magically and i just wanted to make sure do i really need to implement the long list of classes.

Comment: @AbuHamzah unfortunately, you do. Every element that will be encountered by the JSON deserializer should be accounted for. Yay dynamic types :\

Answer (score 0):

Try using built in serializer for JSON - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx : `new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person)).ReadObject(stream1);`.

If it is not enough to read your objects consider using JSON.Net ( http://json.codeplex.com/) -  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Labels>(json);`

Comment: please see my updated question, i try to implement what it showed in msdn but no success.

Comment: The approach I used for similar case is to construct objects till WriteObject call of serializer returns JSON similar to what I need to parse. You need to build whole tree of objects. Classes written by jcolebrand φ are about right amount of objects you need.